# Capture return value from fold expression in std::apply

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I have a simple snippet that tries to illustrate what I'm trying to do.
I pack a few class instances in a tuple and iterate over them using std::apply.
I'd like to capture two values:

1. If a matching key was found
2. If a key was found, return the result of the `do_test` call

I capture (2) in a variable `fn_ret`, but for (1), I can't tell if a key was found while iterating over the tuple. I think I might need to store/get the result of `search_tuple(args)` somehow before passing it in the fold expression. How do I go about doing that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

class foo
{
    public:
    foo(int i) : key_(i){}
    
    int get_key()
    {
        return key_;
    }

    int do_test()
    {
        std::cout << "ran test for key=" << key_ << "\n";
        return -1;
    }
    private:
    int key_;
};

int main()
{
    std::tuple tup { foo{1}, foo{2}, foo{3}, foo{4}, foo{5}, foo{6}, foo{7}, foo{8} };
    int key = 4;
    int fn_ret = 0;
    std::apply
        (
            [key, &fn_ret](auto&... args)
            {
                auto search_tuple = [key, &fn_ret](auto& x) {
                    int foo_key = x.get_key();
                    cout << "current key=" << foo_key << "\n";
                    if (foo_key == key)
                    {
                        std::cout << "found matching key, running test!\n";
                        fn_ret = x.do_test();
                        return 0;
                    }
                    return -1;
                };
                (search_tuple(args) && ...);
            }, tup
        );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To start with, you may need to pass both key and fn_ret in the second lambda expression, also. `search_tuple = [key, &fn_ret](auto& x)`

Comment: With that change the code works to a reasonable extent. The key is found if it is there and the result of do_test is stored in fn_ret. Is that good enough?

Comment: That covers point 2 . In the case a key is not present, I haven't been able to come up with a good way to propagate a "no key found" error code.

Comment: Check my answer. Either a special initial value in `fn_ret` could be used or another boolean variable could be passed from main along with `key` and `fn_ret`.

Comment: You can `return (search_tuple(args) && ...);` directly in the lambda so that the return value of `std::apply` indicates whether the key was not found.

Comment: Oh duh, you're right 康桓瑋, I'm kicking myself for not thinking about that. If you add that as the answer, I'll accept it. I think its the cleaner solution.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I incorporated your suggestion in my answer. I hope that is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works to a reasonable extent. It stores a special initial value in `fn_ret` to check whether the key was found. Instead an additional boolean variable could be passed by reference from main along with `key` and `fn_ret`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

class foo
{
    public:
    foo(int i) : key_(i){}
    
    int get_key()
    {
        return key_;
    }

    int do_test()
    {
        std::cout << "ran test for key=" << key_ << "\n";
        return key_*key_; // Some operation on the key
    }
    private:
    int key_;
};

int main()
{
    std::tuple tup { foo{1}, foo{2}, foo{3}, foo{4}, foo{5}, foo{6}, foo{7}, foo{8} };
    int key = 10;
    int fn_ret = -1;
    bool key_fnd = false;
    std::apply
        (
            [key, &fn_ret, &key_fnd](auto&... args) {
                auto search_tuple = [key, &fn_ret, &key_fnd](auto& x) {
                    int foo_key = x.get_key();
                    cout << "current key=" << foo_key << "\n";
                    if (foo_key == key)
                    {
                        std::cout << "found matching key, running test!\n";
                        key_fnd = true;
                        fn_ret = x.do_test();
                        return 0;
                    }
                    return -1;
                };
                (search_tuple(args) && ...);
            }, tup
        );
    if (!key_fnd) {
      std::cout<<"The key was not found"<<std::endl;
    }
    else {
      std::cout<<"The result of running the test on key "<<key;
      std::cout<<" is "<<fn_ret<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As per 康桓瑋's comment, the logic can be simplified as shown below. Note, the fold expression should be based on `||` to ensure that the key matches with any one of the keys. Also, the evaluation of the fold expression stops when a match has been found.

```
bool key_fnd = std::apply(
                [key, &fn_ret](auto&... args) {
                    auto search_tuple = [key, &fn_ret](auto& x) {
                        int foo_key = x.get_key();
                        cout << "current key=" << foo_key << "\n";
                        if (foo_key == key) {
                            std::cout << "found matching key, running test!\n";
                            fn_ret = x.do_test();
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    };
                    return (search_tuple(args) || ...);
                }, tup
            );
```

Comment: This snippet uses `fn_ret` to infer if a key was found or not. But `fn_ret` is intended to store result of the `do_test` function if it was found. `do_test` could also return an error code that is `-1` for example. In such a situation, I cannot distinguish between a failed `do_test` and "no key found" error.

Comment: An additional boolean variable can be used to keep track of whether the key is found. Then fn_ret can be used as needed. The answer has been updated.